# How to count: Datatable.rows.count excluding deleted rows

Tags: vb.net, dataset, datarow

I'm constantly doing this to avoid removed/deleted rows from my dataset.

```
For Each drX As DataRow In myDataset.Tables("CustInno").Rows
    If drX.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted Then
        iRunRows += 1
    End If
Next
```

is there a quicker or better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

"Better" is a subjective term.  As for "faster", no matter what, something has to loop thru and check the `RowState`.  One thing to do would be to put your loop in a function so you at least are not repeating the code, and can use it on any table:

```
Private Function ActiveRows(dt As DataTable) As Int32
    ... your loop
    Resturn iRunRows 
End Function
```

Or you can use extension methods:

```
Dim activeRowCount = dt.AsEnumerable.
        Count(Function(q) q.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted).
```

It is not likely to be faster - something somewhere has to loop - but it is shorter.

Comment: @IvanPerez if this answers the question please click the checkmark so this gets moved off the UnAnswered List and click the up arrow if it helped.  Accepting answers and up votes help other users find good answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTable` class provides various means to obtain a row set based on `DataRow.State`.

The ['DataTable.Select` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5c0xc84(v=vs.110).aspx) in perhaps the simplest.

`dt.Select("", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)`

Another is to use a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx) and set it `RowStateFilter` property.  This example modifies the `DataTable.DefaultView` property instead on creating a standalone `DataView` instance.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

dt.Columns.Add("c1")
For i As Int32 = 1 To 100
    dt.Rows.Add(i)
Next
dt.AcceptChanges()
Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count.ToString()) ' prints 100

For i As Int32 = 99 To 0 Step -2
    dt.Rows.Item(i).Delete()
Next
Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count.ToString()) ' prints 100

dt.DefaultView.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows
Dim count As Int32 = dt.DefaultView.Count
Debug.Print(count.ToString())   ' prints 50

' loop thru DataView rows
For Each drv As DataRowView In dt.DefaultView
    Dim dr As DataRow = drv.Row
    Debug.Print(dr.Item(0).ToString())
Next
```

Whether or not these methods are better than a looping solution is a subjective call on the observer's part.

Comment: thanks for the info,i never tried just selecting currentrows. :)